# Best way to achive trees haking in node with large file of icons

Tags: node.js

Building a component lib that will have its own icons. It will be used in a nextjs project.

Right now the file with all of the icons looks like this:

```
export const Icons = {
    calendar: (
        <path d="m405 427c7 0 12-2 16-6 4-4 6-9 6-16l0-256c0-6-2-11-6-15-4-4-9-6-16-6l-42 0 0-43-64 0 0 43-86 0 0-43-64 0 0 43-42 0c-7  256c0 7 2 12 6 16 4 4 9 6 16 6z m-21-43l-256 0 0-149 256 0z" />
    ),
    edit: (
        <path d="m128 331l0 53 53 0 158-157-54-54z 5 5-14 0-20l-33-33c-6-5-15-5-20 0l-27 26 54 54z" />
    ),
    'switch-horizontal': (
        <path d="m190 254l28-28-58-58 244 0c11 0 20-9 20-20 0-11-9-20-20-20l-245 0 45-44 14-14-28-27-13 13-92 92z m117 194l14-14 92-91-27 28 58 58-226 0c-11 0-19 9-19 20 0 10 8 19 19 19l226 0-45 45-13 14 27 27z" />
    ),
// 200+ icons
} as const;
```

Then imported and used like this:

```
import { Icons } from './Icons';

export const SvgIcon = ({ className, iconName, disabled, dataTest}: SvgIconProps) => {
    const Icon = Icons[iconName];
    return (
        <svg
            {...{
                xmlns: 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',
                disabled,
                viewBox: '0 0 512 512',
                className,
                'data-test': dataTest || 'svg-icon',
            }}>
            {Icon}
        </svg>
    );
};
```

And after the build I can see that every one becomes PURE:
[image]

Could this be done in a more efficient way regarding performance and tree shaking?

Comment: Not sure what you think is the problem here?

Comment: If I use this component as a server component there is no issue.
But if I use it in a client-component will it shake away all other icons?

Comment: Maybe marking this with nodejs was the wrong tag..

Comment: Yes, [nodejs] has nothing to do with this. Tag it nextjs and with the bundler you are using.

Comment: You are using `Icons[iconName]` in your code. That effectively prevents any treeshaking as `iconName` can be anything and the complete `Icons` object must be available.

Comment: What Im trying to understand is, are there better ways of arrange big files that export a lot of elements.

Comment: And yes, better use named exports instead of an object, *those* a tree-shakeable due to static analysis of `import` statements. Not sure if any bundler is able to tree-shake "unused" property of object literals.